# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 40

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, communication, objectinputstream

I'm building software that passes objects over a TCP socket in Java - using the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream API.
Although, after a minute of smooth communication I started to get the following error:
`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 40`

I saw on stackoverflow how to overcome many types of `type code error`s, but could not find anything about type code 0x40.
I would like to know if anyone has any idea what's the cause of this error and how to fix it.
Thanks!

Here's a pseudocode of my program:
Server module:

```java
    Socket client = server.accept();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

    while(true)
    {
        out.writeObject(new MyObject());
        out.flush();
        out.reset();
    }
```

Client module:

```java
    Socket s = new Socket(IP, PORT);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    while(true)
    {
        MyObject obj = (MyObject) in.readObject();
    }
```

**EDIT:** if that gives anyone of you a clue - I'm also getting a:

`streamcorruptedexception: unexpected reset` error, few times before the invalid type code error.

Comment: `.reset()` shouldn't be there, it resets the mark which you never set. You're not using try-with to protect these resources. More generally, 'pseudocode' isn't going to cut it. As your web searching indicates, this isn't exactly common and the obvious explanation is that bytes are being lost. __If__ the problem is your code, then we'd need to actually see it.

Comment: This socket code with writeObject/readObject should work just fine. You should not get this error from this code.

Comment: @rzwitserloot You are wrong about `reset` - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset() . I think you are confusing it with a different method which is also called `reset`